# Find Object Dictionary in CANopen Device

Tags: can-bus, canopen

I was reading in the CANopen device number EL6751-0010, of course, using the SDO reading command, which I did as follows:

`603  | 40 7A 60 00 00 00 00 00`

and gave me the following error:

`583  | 80 7A 60 00 00 00 02 06`

I realized that this object does not exist.
What should I do to find all the objects of an Object Dictionary?

Finally, I can write and read code in the right place.

Comment: Short or scanning/polling every single entry (there are programs which can do this for you), you could check the EDS file. It should mention all objects present for a certain device.

Comment: @Lundin I don't have the EDS file, I don't know how to get the Object Dictionary. Can you help me ?

Comment: Contact the manufacturer of the device.